# Two If's And An Else

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, if-not-exists

I am trying to run this `t-sql` query but I keep getting an error of

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'

How should this be re-written in order to execute properly?  What I want to achieve is if my variable `@d2 >= GetDate()` I want to run a check to see if `@d2` exists in my table `farquard` if it does then back-up `@d1` by 1 day, if it does not then back-up `@d1` by two days.

This is my with errors syntax, can someone help me?

```
Declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
Set @d1 = '01/01/2013'
Set @d2 = '01/04/2013'

if @d2 >= CAST(GetDate() As Date)
Begin
  if Not Exists(Select TOP 1 * FROM farquard WHERE CAST(stinktoothruth As Date) = @d2)
      BEGIN
        Set @d2 = CAST(GetDate()-2 As Date)
    END
ELSE
      BEGIN
        Set @d2 = CAST(GETDATE()-1 As Date
      END
  END
End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The very last CAST is missing a parenthesis**

```
Set @d2 = CAST(GetDate()-2 As Date
```

should be

```
Set @d2 = CAST(GetDate()-2 As Date)
```

**That fixes the main issue.** (also, once that was fixed you had and extra END at the very end which I removed--or alternately, adding an additional BEGIN.)

```
    Declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
    Set @d1 = '01/01/2013'
    Set @d2 = '01/04/2013'

    if @d2 >= CAST(GetDate() As Date)
      Begin
        if Not Exists(Select TOP 1 * FROM farquard WHERE CAST(stinktoothruth As Date) = @d2)
          BEGIN
            Set @d2 = CAST(GetDate()-2 As Date)
          END
      END
    ELSE
          BEGIN
            Set @d2 = CAST(GETDATE()-1 As Date)
          END
--END REMOVED
```

OR, alternately,

```
Declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
Set @d1 = '01/01/2013'
Set @d2 = '01/04/2013'

if @d2 >= CAST(GetDate() As Date)
Begin
  if Not Exists(Select TOP 1 * FROM farquard WHERE CAST(stinktoothruth As Date) = @d2)
      BEGIN
        Set @d2 = CAST(GetDate()-2 As Date)
    END
ELSE
--BEGIN ADDED
begin
      BEGIN
        Set @d2 = CAST(GETDATE()-1 As Date)
      END
  END
end
```